# List all surveys in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I don't need custom code solutions due to our company have very limited policies about custom code.

I cannot upload a web part.

I am only able to use SharePoint Designer and site admin view.

I want to list all surveys existing on my site, I tried to use CQWP but it does not work. I want to create a site where I can add surveys and then assign them like tasks to our employees.

Answer (score 1):

you should try using Client Object Model ECMA Script to get Survey Lists. You can put that script in your CQWP webpart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Data View Web Part (DVWP) with DataSourceMode="ListOfLists". You can set filters in the CAML based on the ListTemplate value for surveys.